# How to push next view with TTNavigator?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, three20, ttnavigator, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I'm using a modified View-Based Application, where I have starting UIViewController showing a input control & a TTThumbsViewController showing the results. I'm passing them in the AppDelegate using TTNavigator `initWithName:` for the TTThumbsViewController.
I did this by myself reading from the documentation:

The ViewDidLoad method inside my TTThumbsViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
self.photoSource = [[PhotoSource alloc]  
                    initWithType:PhotoSourceNormal  
                    title:myTitle
                    photos:myImages  
                    photos2:nil  
                    ];  
}
```

The implementation of my AppDelegate:

```
@implementation geoFlickrAppDelegate
@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
@synthesize navigator;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application              didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 navigator =[TTNavigator navigator];
 navigator.window = self.window;

 TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
 [map from:@"app://home/" toViewController:[geoFlickrViewController class]];
 [map from:@"app://album/(initWithName:)" toViewController:[AlbumController class]];

 [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"app://home/"]];
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
 return YES;
}

-(void)toGallery:(NSString*)txt
{
 [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:txt]];
}
```

The event inside my UIViewController for pushing the next view:

```
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"app://album/%@",txtSearch.text];
    geoFlickrAppDelegate *appDelegate = (geoFlickrAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate toGallery:str];
}
```

The result from this code is that the input is passed through my AppDelegate in the TTThumbsViewController using `initWithName:` but the never gets pushed in & my `ViewDidLoad` method never gets called. Any idea why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I had an error like this, it was the initializer (in your case initWithName:) returning nil. This is the first thing I would check. If that doesn't solve try setting a breakpoint in `[TTBaseNavigator presentController:parentURLPath:withPattern:action:]`.

If that method is not reached something is wrong with your URL-Map. You may for Example need to urlencode your users input. URL-based Navigation works with URLs. Strings that can not be used in URLs can not be passed unencoded.

If that method is reached, you may use the debugger and step through the code from there to find out whats wrong.

Another thing I would like to mention, is that you really do not need to reference your appDelegate with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` when you like to use the navigator. This is one of the reasons why the navigator is so useful. Try to change the call to:

```
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"app://album/%@",txtSearch.text];
    TTOpenURLFromView(str, self.view);
    TTOpenURL(str); // Three20 < 1.0.3
}
```

You can then get rid of the `toGallery:` method.

Comment: I removed the `toGallery:` method, repaired my init & now my app goes smoothly.. Thanks tonklon.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I have no:

navigator.window = self.window;

and instantiate the window calling:

```
navigator =[TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.window;
```

and also change `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` into

```
 [navigator.window makeKeyAndVisible]
```

Comment: if I remove `navigator.window = self.window;` I get a white screen & the second change didn't change anything actually..

Comment: what is the `self.window` value then? are you using a nib file or not?

Comment: I'm using a nib file in my first view..
Nothing changed when I did by your edit, I get the white screen.